# No default constructor found; nested exception org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.<init>()

Tags: java, spring, testing

I wrote this article:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-normal-controllers.html

And I trying to write a test for my controller:

My code:

```
import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class, WebApplicationContext.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SiteControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnCorrectSite() throws Exception {
        assertThat(true).isTrue();
    }



}
```

When I'm running test i got exception like this:

```
No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.() at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007)


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)

...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testContext': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.test.context.TestContext]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, your TestContext class doesn't have a no-arg constructor, as the message indicates.

Comment: TestContext.class is a class from org.springframework.test.context. What can I do?

Comment: It is not meant to be used with `ContextConfiguration`. I think they create their own `TestContext` class in the linked tutorial.

Comment: @user612925: sorry, I missed that. Since you placed it in the list of configuration classes, I thought it was a custom class of yours. As Sotirios says, it shouldn't be listed there.

Answer (score 0):

In the original article you should define the TestContext class in your classpath, for example:

```
@Configuration
public class TestContext {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);

        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public TodoService todoService() {
        return Mockito.mock(TodoService.class);
    }
}
```

Othe alternative can be using directly the xml files for testing instead of java classes:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:testContext.xml", "classpath:exampleApplicationContext-web.xml"})
```